# Identify subsets where all values are the same

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (ID, CASENO, STATUS) that has many rows, all with a unique ID - there are groupings of rows by CASENO - I would like to create a query that shows me all the CASENO values where all the rows for that CASENO have a STATUS the same

```
ID   CASENO   STATUS
1    123      X
2    123      Y
3    123      X
4    234      X
5    234      X
6    567      Z
7    567      Z
8    567      Z
9    789      A
10   789      B
```

So this would return 234 and 567 because they have the same values in STATUS

Answer (score 5):

```
select caseno
from my_table
group by caseno
having count(distinct status) = 1
```

Any `NULL`s will be implicitly ignored in aggregates, rather than causing the aggregate itself to return a `NULL` i.e. your `count(distinct status)` should be OK even if you have `NULL` status values.

**UPDATE:**
To give a listing of status-counts by `caseno`, you could do this:

```
select caseno, status, count(*)
from my_table
group by caseno, status
-- include next line if you only want cases where the count is > 1
-- having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks @davek - if I wanted to flip it and show the ones that had multiple STATUS and the value,count, how could I do that? So my query would return 123|X|1, 123|Y|1, 789|A|1, 789|B|1

Comment: Saw your edit - thanks Dave - it returns zero results though (with the HAVING line unremmed). Is it getting confused with the multiple references to STATUS? (In fact with or without the HAVING line, it returns the same results)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: that should be a count(*) in the HAVING term in the second example. I've changed it in my answer.

Comment: But that is then not counting distinct statuses, just giving me ones where there are more than one occurence of a status

Comment: Done it in a roundabout way `select CASENO,status,count(*) from my_table where CASENO in ( select caseno from my_table group by caseno having count(distinct status) > 1) group by caseno,status order by caseno`

Comment: @Mike: I really believe your additional question deserves its own thread. You should have posted a new question.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike could you please post the query result after executing @davek query. I can see it is giving desired results.

[image: Result Set]

Comment: The query is returning zero results because the CASENOs with multiple statuses only have one occurrence of each status. If 789 had another row with a status of B, it would return 789|B|2. What I want is 789|A|1 and 789|B|2 (ie: for 789, there are two statuses A and B, A has one count and B has two)

Comment: @Mike having Count(*) >0 would give you the result that you are expecting...

what am I missing here :(

    select caseno, status, count(*) as Count
    from my_table
    group by caseno, status
    having count(*) > 0